# Addresses in C Language

Tags: c

The GCC compiler on CSLab translates the following C function:

```c
int func(int x) {
    return 13 + x;
}
```

Into the following Assembly code:

```
    func:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl $13, %eax
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

I have completed this code and was then asked the following question:

> In the Assembly code for func shown in the previous question, suppose %rsp has the value
>
> 0x7fffffffe3e0
>
> What is the address corresponding to the parameter  (local variable) x? Include the 0x prefix.
>
> (Note that the address has 12 significant hex digits, or 6 bytes. > The value for the top two hex digits is 0.  Omit the 0s to the left just as shown above.)

I answered 0xd and it was incorrect.

Comment: The only place I can imagine you getting `0xd` from is the constant 13 in the C source.  But that has nothing at all to do with the *address* of `x`.  Note that the question gives you a value for `%rsp` as additional information.  Although it is conceivable that that's a red herring, you should at least consider that it might be essential information needed to answer the question.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea where to go from there. Where do I start?

Comment: *"Note that the address has 12 significant hex digits..."* paragraph means that your answer should have 12 hex digits. You have 1 hex digit.

Comment: Let's start with this: Do you know what "address" means? -- OT: The statement on `%rsp` is not really clear, because it does not say _when_ the register has this value. At the entry into the function? Later in the function? Before the call of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the given value for `%rsp` as `0x7fffffffe3e0`, we have

```
movq %rsp, %rbp
```

which copies the value of `%rsp` to `%rbp`, then we have

```
movl -4(%rbp), %eax
addl $13, %eax
```

We copy *something* to `%eax` and add `13` to it, so that *something* must be `x`.  That *something* is `-4(%rbp)`, which translates to "an object 4 bytes below the address value stored in `%rbp`".

Thus, the address of `x` must be `0x7fffffffe3e0 - 4`, or `0x7fffffffe3dc`.

Read up on your x86 assembly addressing modes.